# C++ sort vectors time complexity

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, vector, std

Suppose I have a `vector<vector<int>> L` with N vectors, and total number of `int`s summed across all vectors is at most M. What is the tightest time complexity of the standard C++ sort `sort(L.begin(), L.end())`?

The `vector<int>` comparison function has runtime at most O(M), so an obvious bound is O(NM log N). But if we implement standard mergesort, we can see that in each of the O(log N) levels at most O(M) integer comparisons are done, so the runtime is O((N+M) log N). This is because comparing two vectors of length A and B takes O(min(A,B)) time.

Does the C++ standard guarantee that the runtime is O((N+M) log N)?

Comment: FYI: If you really care about complexity, consider using Radix Sort. Counting sorts have improved complexity over compare sorts.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't enough information.  You also need to know the **distribution** of the `M` values across the `N` vectors.  When you have that, then it's straight forward to find the overall complexity:

1. `std::sort` has a complexity of `O(N·log(N))` comparisons.
2. `std::vector` uses `std::lexicographical_compare(v1, v2)` for comparison, which has a complexity of `O(min(v1.size(), v2.size()))` comparisons.
3. `int` comparison has a complexity of `O(1)`.
4. We'll let `E(M, N)` be a function on `M`, `N` that returns the **mean** number of ***minimum elements*** between every pair of inner vectors.

   - For example, if you have a **uniform distribution**, this is
     trivially equal to `M/N`.
5. Take the product: 
   `Big Oh = N·log(N)·E(M, N)·1`.

   - For a **uniform distribution**, this would be `M·log(N)`.

You can use [Discrete Probability Distribution theory](http://www.probabilityformula.org/discrete-probability-distributions.html) to figure out what the `E(M, N)` function is for any distribution of `M` across `N`.

---

**Edit 1**: To drive the point of how/why this matters: Consider a distribution that *always* makes my vectors look like:

```
outer[0].size() == 1,
outer[1].size() == 1,
outer[2].size() == 1,
...,
outer[M-1].size() == (M - N + 1)
```

In this case, `E(M, N) = 1`, because `std::lexicographical_compare` will only ever have **one** other element to compare to for any pair of elements.  Thus, for this particular distribution, I will *always* have a complexity of `O(N·log(N))`.  But with a uniform distribution, I'll have `O(M·log(N))`.

---

**Edit 2**: Following the comment where you define your distribution, let's try and find the `E(M, N)`.

First, notice that there are in total `T = (N choose 2) = N(N - 1)(1/2)` different combinations of vector comparisons.

One (and only one) combination will take `X = O((M - N + 2)(1/2))` comparisons, and has probability `P(X) = 1/T` to occur.

Every other combination will require just  `1` comparison (`O(1)`), and so those cases occur with probability `P(1) = (T - 1)/T`.

Finding the mean is simple: `X·P(X) + 1·P(1)`.

Given this, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X*(1%2FT)+%2B+1*((T-1)%2FT)+where+T+%3D+(N+choose+2),+X+%3D+(M-N%2B2)(1%2F2)) says: `E(M, N) = (M + (N - 2) N)/((N - 1) N)`.

Multiplying that function by `N log(N)` gives us [`(M + (N - 2) N) log(N) / (N - 1)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(N)(log(N))(X*(1%2FT)+%2B+1*((T-1)%2FT))+where+X+%3D+(M-N%2B2)%2F2,+T+%3D+(N+choose+2)), which can be further simplified to the Big Oh you're looking for: **`O((M/N + N) log(N))`**.

Comment: Why do we use the mean comparison time for every pair of inner vectors? Shouldn't it be the mean comparison time for every pair that is compared by the C++ sort algorithm?

Comment: Thanks, I get that. I'm just wondering about this case: N-2 vectors of length 1, 2 vectors of length (M-N+2)/2. Clearly this should take very little time too. However the comparison time can be up to (M-N+2)/2. Does that mean the C++ sort will take (M-N+2)/2 * N log N time? I think we need to know what exactly are the comparisons done by the sort algorithm...

Comment: Okay well, again, this takes a bit of probability theory to understand.  I'll try my best to explain.  Please update your question w/ an edit giving the distribution while I type out the answer. :)

Comment: @Wakaka Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Maybe I wasn't too clear about my question, but my main concern is: why is the time complexity of sort O(N E(M,N) log N)? I'm looking for the worst case, rather than the average case. In particular this is the mean comparison time if **all** (N choose 2) vector comparisons are done. But what if C++ sort chooses to do a subset of the comparisons (O(N log N) in total) that take the greatest amount of time?

Comment: The standard sort in stl is not implemented as merge sort. It generally uses introsort as its cache behavior is better. If you want to use merge sort, you need to use stable_sort. To analyze the worst case behavior. According to the standard: for sort: Complexity: O(N log(N)) (where N == last - first) comparisons and for stable_sort: Complexity: It does at most N log2(N) (where N == last - first) comparisons; if enough extra memory is available, it is N log(N).

Comment: @Wakaka I use `E(M, N)` b/c I assume sort does not perform redundant comparisons.  The worst case complexity depends on the pre-existing order of elements. The STL promises `O(N log(N))` regardless of order.  So the # of inner vector comparisons remain the same.  All that's left is the complexity of the comparisons, which depends on the distribution.  `N log(N)` comparisons implies that each of the inner vectors will be compared to some other inner vector *at least once*, and since I've assumed no redundancies, that means how long they take depends on the *mean*, hence my usage of `E(M, N)`.

Comment: Well, Landau notation can often be "prettified" intentionally so the last sentence does not make much sense. O((M+(N-2)N)/(N-1)*log(N)) "is" O((N + M/N) log(N)) and that in turn "is" O((M+N) log(N)) so the OP's guess was correct, just less specific.

Answer (score 2):

In case your Integers are **more or less random** <sup>1)</sup>, most comparisons only need to compare the first few integers of each vector (until the first mismatch), so in practice / on average

**M (counterintuitively) doesn't have any effect on the algorithmic complexity**

To give you some Idea: Even, if your vectors have **infinite length** and the most frequently occurring integer has a probability `p` of 50%, you need **less than 2 comparisons on average**:

```
k < ∑ i*p^i = p/(1-p)^2 | p=0.5 
k < ∑ i*0.5^i = 2;
```

For other probabilities the results are:

```
60% -> k <  2.5
70% -> k <  3.4
80% -> k <  5.0
90% -> k < 10.0
```

Keep in mind that all those numbers are **upper bounds** for the **average number of integer comparisons** and **independent** of the number of elements in the vector

<sup>1)</sup> By random I don't mean random in a cryptographic sense. The numbers don't even have to pass most quality tests for random numbers. The only requirement is that they don't form the same prefix - which grows with the length of a vector - in a systematic manner.
Except for malicious input I can't currently think of a realistic example that would not qualify as "more or less random", but there is probably something else.

Comment: `M` matters here for the same reason `N` matters in `find`: some comparisons can end early, yes, but average case is still `O(N/2) = O(N)`.  When `M >> N`, `M` can become significant.

Comment: @Brian: No! Consider N == 2, M == 1000 (so two vectors of size 500) and let the integers be between 0 and 10. The probability that the last two integers are significant is 0.1^500. If you let M grow, the probability that the newly added integer makes a difference falls exponentially, while the length only growth linearly

Comment: That's true, but only because of the additional constraint you've placed on the integers.  OP hasn't placed such a constraint, and when we remove it, M is significant even in that example.

Comment: @Brian: That is why I said *"In case your Integers are more or less random"*. If you have to harden your algorithm against an attacker, that can choose arbitrary numbers (namely e.g. only `1`) this of course doesn't help. But for most other applications you get a much more realistic estimate of how the algorithms will behave if you assume that the comparison terminates early. It is a bit like the situation with a hash table: Your worst case performance is O(n) and in some situations this is important but usually, you just assume that lookup is O(1)

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive in your answer on what it means for integers to be "more or less random", then?